# how to get list of post formats supported by theme?

Tags: post-formats

After adding support for a selection of post formats like this:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'video' ) );
```

how can I then get the list of supported post formats back?

I'm building a theme where the user can toggle support for postformat, and I want other admin elements to reflect what post formats the user has configured the theme to support.

so I'm looking for something like

```
current_theme_supports( 'post-formats'); // outputs boolean
```

but that outputs just true or false, whereas I want to get an array of the post formats actually registered..

what would be the correct WordPress function to call (or constant/global var) to look at for this?

I want something like this:

```
get_supported_post_formats(); // out: array('aside', 'video')
```

Comment: I wanted to tag this with theme-support but the tag is not registered, and I can't add new tags.. could an admin consider this as a new tag?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters Formats are a taxonomy..... so can you do something with that?  LIke maybe using http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Listing_the_terms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from `post_format_meta_box`;

```
if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-formats' ) ) {
    $post_formats = get_theme_support( 'post-formats' );

    if ( is_array( $post_formats[0] ) ) {
        print_r( $post_formats[0] );
        // Array( supported_format_1, supported_format_2 ... )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

get_theme_support( 'post-formats' ) will return the array of supported formats.

Comment: For some reason the array returned is nested, why is that? $post_formats[0] is the only parent key, so why is it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do array_shift to avoid the 0th element.

```
$temp = get_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
var_dump(array_shift( $temp ));
```

if you need it by key value pair, then

```
$temp = get_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
$ar = array_shift( $temp );
$ar = array_combine($ar, $ar);
var_dump($ar);
```